# Is there a function/approach to compare discrete with continuous data to calculate the x-shift needed to overlay them?

Tags: curve-fitting, data-processing, discretization

I am fairly new to Python and I am stuck on one issue.
I have two data-sets where one is a continuous curve and the other I discretizised to mimick a realistic measurement device. To simulate the spatial off-set I createt None values in-between elements, since the sensitive thickness of the measurement device is very thinn and inbetween is mostly air.[The discrete points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIlVI.png)
[Teh continuous curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFVaI.png)

These two vectors I would like to overlay to calculate the x-shift needed to get as good fitting as possible.

Only way I figured out was to interpolate between the points with scipy minimize but since that carry some uncertainty I only want to base it on the datapoints itself. Python doesn't seem to like None values, and replacing with zeros the output was simply very wrong.

Any help or guidance is greately appreciated, also if there is a better way to discretizise the data.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask]. Add your dataset as a link or copy paste it (no screenshot).